# Extension with protocols of the Cocoapods library not called

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods, swift-protocols

I am using a third party library [Dropdown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) which uses a Tableview to show the dropdown. I want add a header to it but dont want to change any thing in lib classes.
So I have created an extension class with following contents

```
extension UITableViewDelegate where Self: DropDown {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 22))
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 22))
        label.text = "Hello Header"
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        return view
    }
}
```

But this is not working. 
Is it a proper way? Can someone help me out?

Note: While adding the same to library I am able to see the Header. But I dont want to edit the library classes.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `DropDown` is a subclass from `UIView`, not `UITableView`. It has a `tableView` constant (as you could see it [here](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown/blob/master/DropDown/src/DropDown.swift#L84)) which treated as a subview, hence the `tableView` dataSource and delegate is handled by the `DropDown` class itself; As implemented in the [library source code](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown/blob/master/DropDown/src/DropDown.swift#L999), you could see that:

```
extension DropDown: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { ...
```

Means that  you should also do it this way instead of declaring the extension as:

```
extension UITableViewDelegate where Self: DropDown {
```

---

Therefore:

```
extension DropDown: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 22.0))
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 22.0))
        label.text = "Hello Header"
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        return view
    }

    // don't forget to implement this one too:
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 22.0
    }
}
```

Should achieve it.

---

**Update:**

Since the library already has an extension that conforms to `UITableViewDelegate`, you might face compile-time error as:

> Redundant conformance of 'DropDown' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'

So you could declare your extension as:

```
extension DropDown {
    // same desired methods implemented here...
}
```

without the need of reconforming to `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Just a small question. DropDown has already an extension which conforms to UITableViewDelegate and now when we redefine extension which conforms to same Delegate..  Shouldn't it give re-declaration error?

Comment: You're right @SahilManchanda, just updated my answer ;)

Comment: After changing also, i'm not able to see the header. The control is not coming to this delegates in extension while running

Comment: @pradeep are you sure that you have implemented `heightForHeaderInSection` delegate method?

Comment: Yes I have implemented.

Comment: @pradeep could you try to implement any method of `UITableViewDelegate` and a breakpoint in it? so we can distinguish what's the reason of why the header is not showing...

Comment: I have placed 'tableView: heightForRowAt indexPath:' and kept breakpoint but control is not coming to it as well.   Also I tried adding 'viewForHeaderInSection' inside the lib DropDown.swift them I am able to see the header. But I dont want to change the lib classes